# Chrome extension security

Tags: security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging, chrome-native-messaging

I am developing a GWT based client server web application.

The application installs a web site on the IIS.
When clients first browse to the web site, they need to run a local installation, which installs a local process and a NPAPI plugin on the client computer.

The client runs in browsers such as IE, Chrome and Firefox,
and uses the NPAPI plugin to send messages to the local process.
The local process is used for accessing the file system, registry, etc.

In order to prevent other web sites from using the NPAPI plugin,
When a user first login, the server sends him a hash of a string which contains the URL of the site + some other data.
The NPAPI plugin has access to the current URL of the browser, and also creates the same hash and compares the two.

Due to Chrome upcoming end of support of NPAPI plugins, I am trying to replace the plugin with a Chrome extension, and a native messaging host.
The extension can't be limited to a certain domain because it can be used from many domains.

I am trying to figure out a way to prevent other web sites from using the extension to send messages to the native host but can't find a way to do it.
Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish that?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having the extension be limited to a specific domain, and then having the other domains iframe that domain and communicate via `postMessage`? You could have a whitelist of domains in the JS of the iframe, and validate the message origin against that list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thats a good advice. I didn't mention it before but many installations are on Intranet only and don't has access to my domain. I also wanted to avoid maintaining a white list, becasue there are a lot of installations currently ( some which I don't know their domains), and I also don't want new installation to wait until their domain is added to the list.